# Round displayed value in Numbers for iOS to 2 decimals

Tags: iphone, numbers, ios

Say I have the value 2.3638383 in a cell in Numbers for iOS (iPhone). Can I format the numbers so only 2 decimal places are shown (rounded to nearest decimal)? So 2.3638383 would be displayed as 2.36?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it's a built in formatting command so you don't have too mess with formulas like FLOOR or ROUND.

[image]

Here are the steps:

1) Select the cell containing the number
2) Select the paint brush from top bar (4th from right)
3) Then select `Format` Tab (rightmost)
4) From dropdown select `Number`
5) Tap the `i` to the right of `Number`
6) From `Number` tab and under `Decimals` select 2 from dropdown